# For a random iid sample of size n, probability of some $X_j$ of being minimum

Tags: probability

Suppose we have an identically and independently distributed sample of continuous random variables $X_1, ..., X_n$.

How do I calculate, using integration areas, the probability that for some $j$, $X_j = \underset{(X_i)}{min} X_i $ ?

I know that there's a logic that goes like this:  since they are identical and independent, each has the same probability of being the minimum. And, since one of them must be the minimum, we have that each random variable has probability $1/n$.

But I tried explicitly calculating this for a $U(0,1)$ pdf (which should arguably be the easiest) and I kept getting stuck. For two RVs, $X$ and $Y$, calculating $Pr(X \leq Y)$ is straightforward, since we define the areas: $x, y \in [0,1]$ and $x \leq y$ resulting in:

$$Pr(X \leq Y) = \int_0^1 \int_0^y f(x,y) dxdy = \frac{x^2}{2}\vert_0^1 = \frac{1}{2}$$

Now, adding another random variable $Z$, and taking: $Pr(X = min\{X,Y,Z\}) = Pr(X \leq Y, X \leq Z)$, and having $x, y, z \in [0,1]$, $x \leq y$, $x \leq z$, and taking integrals as above, results in $1/6$ (instead of the actual answer, $1/3$). I suspect this has to do with splitting between two cases: $y \leq z$ and $y \geq z$, but I don't see how to make such observation fit in the areas of integration.

Comment: You could write in detail what you did.  I suspect the problem may be that $X\le Y$ and $X\le Z$ are not independent events.

Comment: The joint pdf $f(x,y,z) = 1$ since they are independent RVs, but the events surely are not independent - but I thought that the non-independence would be taken care of by defining the appropriate areas of integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event

$X=min(X,Y,Z)$ can be written as

$$(0<X<Y<Z<1)\cup (0<X<Z<Y<1)=A\cup B$$

1.

$$\mathbb{P}[A]=\int_0^1  dx\int_x^1dy\int_y^1dz=\frac{1}{6}$$

2.

$$\mathbb{P}[B]=\int_0^1  dx\int_x^1dz\int_z^1dy=\frac{1}{6}$$

Thus

$$\mathbb{P}[X=min(X,Y,Z)]=\frac{1}{6}+ \frac{1}{6}= \frac{1}{3}  $$

Comment: I suspected as much. Thank you.